# How to Install Ubuntu 16.04 with Window 7, Dual Boot

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows, windows-7

Greetings;
As in the boot options of my desktop, it is showing as 'Legacy + UEFI".
Windows 7 is installed.

I want to us both the OS and need to have the GRUB installed.
Last year had a problem and was unable to see the GRUB for boot options.

Kindly Help

Thanking you

Comment: You need to install Ubuntu in the same mode Win7 is, in order to have a proper dual-boot.

Answer (score 1):

Install Ubuntu with the same mode as Windows i.e Legacy + UEFI as per your OP.

Install Grub.

Once installed, run `sudo update-grub` and it will detect Windows installed in the other partition and add it to the Grub's list of available boot options which are displayed when you boot up the system.

Make sure not to format the partition in which Windows is installed.

Comment: Thanks So Much @Alok _Rajawat. Can you please tell me how to install ubuntu in the same mode ( Legacy + UEFI). I am unable to do that.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to be noted is that Windows 7 is always installed using **Legacy mode**. *UEFI mode* is supported by Windows 7+ versions.
So you will have to ***install Ubuntu in Legacy mode.***
And make sure not to format System reserved partition and partition where Windows is installed.